# Show Best three Routes between two co-ordinate points

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mapkit

I'm Newbie to iOS development as well as to `MapKit Framework`. I want to get `Best three Routes` between two location (for ex. `New York to California`).

It can be done using `MapKit framework`. Please if any one have any idea or tutorial. Please help me to get this done. Hope for the Best.

Thanks in Advance.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this libraries:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mtdirectionskit

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/p2msroutingview

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response.But, I want to use only MapKit Framework not any third party framework like Google Map SDK. If u could tell me if it is possible through MapKit